# Process grep gives ambiguous output

Tags: linux, shell, sh, init.d

I have this init.d script where i am checking the status of an application, The expected output should be 
"Application is running with PID: XXXX"

Anyways, i'll show you the code that i have used:

```
ps -ef|grep -v grep |grep Jazz |grep -v "Jazz status"|awk '{ if ( $2 != "") print "Jazz Running with PID:",$2"; else print "Jazz not running";}'
```

When i run this on the terminal i get the following output:

```
    Jazz Running with PID: 6261
    Jazz Running with PID: 30077
```

When i remove the print statement and output $2 i get the following output:

```
#ps -ef|grep -v grep |grep Jazz |grep -v "Jazz status"|awk '{ if ( $2 != "") print $2}'   
300077
```

I expect the output to be

```
Jazz Running with PID: 300773
```

I am stumped as to why i am getting two PID's in the first case? 
P.S the first PID keeps changing, similar to showing me the PID of the command itself.

---

**Edit:**
Output of: `ps -ef|grep Jazz`

```
netcool  12744     1  5 13:03 ?        00:06:06 /opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=38692 -Dosgi.install.area=/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer -Dosgi.configuration.area=/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile/servers/server1/configuration -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dosgi.framework.extensions=com.ibm.cds,com.ibm.ws.eclipse.adaptors -Xshareclasses:name=webspherev85_1.6_64_%g,nonFatal -Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ibmorb.jar -classpath /opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile/properties:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/properties:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/lib/startup.jar:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar -Dibm.websphere.internalClassAccessMode=allow -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xcompressedrefs -Xscmaxaot4M -Xscmx60M -Dws.ext.dirs=/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/java/lib:/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile/classes:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/classes:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/lib:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/installedChannels:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/lib/ext:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/web/help:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime -Dderby.system.home=/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/derby -Dcom.ibm.itp.location=/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/bin -Djava.util.logging.configureByServer=true -Duser.install.root=/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile -Djava.ext.dirs=/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/tivoli/tam:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/ext -Djavax.management.builder.initial=com.ibm.ws.management.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder -Dpython.cachedir=/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile/temp/cachedir -Dwas.install.root=/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer -Djava.util.logging.manager=com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WsLogManager -Dserver.root=/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile -Dcom.ibm.security.jgss.debug=off -Dcom.ibm.security.krb5.Krb5Debug=off -Dfas.install.location=/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/admin -Dfas.ui.install.location=/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/admin_ui -Djava.library.path=/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/lib/native/linux/x86_64/:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/amd64/default:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/bin:/usr/lib:/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/reporting/cognos/bin64: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/endorsed_apis:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/endorsed:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/endorsed_apis:/opt/IBM/tivoli/webSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/endorsed -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile/properties/wsjaas.conf -Djava.security.policy=/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile/properties/server.policy com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher -nosplash -application com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer /opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile/config JazzSMNode01Cell JazzSMNode01 server1
netcool  19735 19678  0 14:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep Jazz
```

---

**Edit**
Full init.d script that i have used:

```
#!/bin/sh

USER="xxxxxxx"
PASSWORD="xxxxxx"
start() {
su - netcool -c "/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile/bin/startServer.sh server1"

RETVAL=$?
return $RETVAL
}
stop() {
su - netcool -c "/opt/IBM/tivoli/jazzSM/profile/bin/stopServer.sh server1 -username ${USER} -password ${PASSWORD}"

RETVAL=$?
return $RETVAL
}
status() {
ps -ef|grep -v grep |grep Jazz |grep -v awk |grep -v "Jazz status" |awk '{ if ( $2!= "") print "Jazz is running with PID:",$2; else print "Jazz is not running";}'
#pid=$(pgrep -f Jazz) && echo "Jazz Running with PID: $pid" || echo "Jazz is not running"
}
case $1 in
"start")
start
;;
"stop")
stop
;;
"status")
status
;;
"restart"|"reload")
stop
start
;;

*)
echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|reload}"
RETVAL=1
esac
exit 0
```

Hope this helps

---

**UPDATE**
Based upon @jlliagre suggestion, running the following command still gave me more than one PID as the output:

```
[root@hjkpnlinst04 ~]# pid=$(pgrep -f jazzSM) && echo "Jazz Running with PID: $pid" || echo "Jazz is not running"
Jazz Running with PID: 12744
13176
13299
```

For now i am running this command, which seems to give me the required output when the process is running, however fails to give me the "else" output when the process is not running:

```
ps -ef|grep -v grep |grep Jazz |grep -v awk |grep -v "Jazz status" |awk '{ if ( $2!= "") print "Jazz is running with PID:",$2; else print "Jazz is not running";}'
```

Comment: I'll suggest you to ps -ef | grep -v 'Jazz status' | grep Jazz | grep -v grep

Comment: The above command gives me the right output, but i want a elegant way to give the output, instead of the entire process detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are finding awk.  You are excluding grep, but not awk.
Better way to do this is using the pgrep command, e.g.:

```
echo "java is running with pids ", `pgrep java`
```

will list all pids Java processes are running with.  It looks at the process image name only, not on the command line.  I am not sure how portable pgrep is but it is there on Linux, FreeBSD and OS X, so good enough for me.

But looking at your updated answer I see that you are looking for the command line keyword, so like @jlliagre suggests, you should use -f switch.  The advantage of pgrep is that it is smart enough to exclude itself, unlike the chain of awks and greps.

Comment: Thank you, including grep -v awk did it. But i haven't faced this issue before. Anyways, i am just curious how do i implement the same using pgrep?

Answer (score 1):

That command should work (assuming `pgrep` is available):

```
pid=$(pgrep -f JazzSMNode01Cell) && echo "Jazz Running with PID: $pid" || echo "Jazz is not running"
```

Comment: The first command yields no output, however the second command gives me the output, but with two PID's again. 
`# /etc/init.d/Jazz status
Jazz Running with PID: 12744
16347`

Comment: It would help if you give the command line used by the Jazz process. `ps -ef|grep Jazz` (add it to you original question, not here as comments do not retain formatting).

Comment: What is the name of your init.d script? See my updated answer anyway.

Comment: Jazz. I run it as `Jazz status`

Comment: That was the issue, please try my updated script which uses "jazzSM" instead of "Jazz" to avoid picking the init.d script.

Comment: I have edited my question to include output of the command. However, still no luck with this.

Comment: The issue is there are still multiple processes running with jazzSM in their command line, answer updated again with a new attempt.